# List resources by from Azure by tag

Tags: c, azure, azure-sdk

I have the following simple piece of code for listing resources by tag from Azure, but I cannot get filter working. What am I doing wrong?

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Veeam.Core.Extensions;

string clientId = "...";
string tenantId = "...";
var clientSecret = "...";
string subscriptionId = "...";
```

// the code works with and operator but not works with or operator
var filterTags = "tagName eq 'asdf' or tagValue eq '1234'";

```
var e = ArmEnvironment.AzurePublicCloud;
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId));
var resourcesPageable= subscription.GetGenericResourcesAsync(filter: filterTags);
var tempResources = await resourcesPageable.ToListAsync();
Console.WriteLine(tempResources.Count);
```

The response from server is:

Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: InvalidFilterInQueryString

```
Content:                                                                                                                                          
{"error":{"code":"InvalidFilterInQueryString","message":"Invalid $filter 'tagName eq 'asdf' and tagValue '1234'' specified in the query string."}}
```

IntelliSense documentation says:

//For example, to filter for a tag name and value, use $filter=tagName eq 'tag1' and tagValue eq 'Value1'. When you filter by a tag name and value, the tags for each resource are not returned in the results.

Is it really the or operator not supported?

Comment: I think  the correct syntax for filtering resources based on tags is using the "and" operator. The "or" operator is not directly supported in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it really the or operator not supported?

Yes, only `and` operations are allowed in $filter tag to list the resources but not `or` operation. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list?view=rest-resources-2021-04-01).

Try below operations to list the resources with `tagname`/`tagvalue`:

```
$filter=tagname eq '{tagname}'
$filter=tagname eq '{tagname}' and tagvalue eq '{tagvalue}'
$filter=startswith(tagname, '{tagname prefix}')
```

I have implemented the same with the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Repository;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "<Client_ID>";
        string tenantId = "<Tenant_ID>";
        var clientSecret = "<Client_secret>";
        string subscriptionId = "<Subscription_ID>";
        string filterTags = "tagname eq 'abc' and tagvalue eq '123'"; 

        var e = ArmEnvironment.AzurePublicCloud;
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
        var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId));
        var resourcesPageable = subscription.GetGenericResourcesAsync(filter: filterTags);
        var tempResources = new List<GenericResource>();

        await foreach (var resource in resourcesPageable)
        {
            tempResources.Add(resource);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Number of resources: {tempResources.Count}");

        foreach (var resource in tempResources)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Resource ID: {resource.Id}, Resource Name: {resource.Data.Name}, Resource Type: {resource.Data.ResourceType}");
        }

    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pravallika, the documentation clearly says "Multiple substring operations can also be combined using and/or operators." SO I would expect or operator is supported.